# If I want to constrain a signal to +- 5 V, what arrangement and rating of zener will I need?

Tags: zener

I have set up a circuit with two zener diodes head-to-head with a resistor upstream, to limit a circuit signal voltage to +- 5V. On measurement, the 0.7 V of one zener appears to be summing with the 5.0 V of the other, creating a bound of +- 5.7 V. I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour, but leads me to think 4.3 V zeners head to tail might give the +- 5V bounding I'm looking for.

Then with the resistor, I had started with 100 Ohm, but it looks like a Zener's 'stiffness' isn't that high, so might need a much higher value resistor to catch swings of a few volts each way.

Have I understood the situation correctly?

Comment: You'll have a fair tolerance on your +/- 5 V, but given that you've got it all right.

Comment: Zener diodes are "stiffer" at higher voltages; below about 5 or 6 volts they're pretty poor for limiting voltage. I would recommend you consider schottky diodes to the rails, if you have ±5 volt rails available. Or a circuit involving one or two TL431s might do the job.